# Calling a plugin function after an entry is deleted?

Tags: plugin-development

Is there a way to call a custom function after an entry is deleted successfully?

If there isn't, is there a record of the deleted record stored anywhere?

Currently, I am thinking of editing the `actionPerformAction` in `elementIndexController`, but I don't want to edit the application files, so if there is another method I would prefer that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [simple plugin](http://pluginfactory.io) that listens to the [onDeleteEntry](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#entries-onDeleteEntry) [event](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/hooks-and-events#events).

There is an `entry` parameter passed into that event that is the [EntryModel](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entrymodel) object that represents the entry that was just deleted.

Comment: craft()->on('entries.onDeleteEntry', function(Event $event) { Craft::log(" HELLO delete on delete ######\n\n", LogLevel::Info, true); });  I created a plugin and added this to the init function, but it isnt being called. Do you know why it might be? Also, I am using  craft 2.6.

Comment: @user2997606 Just to check, did you remember to install your plugin via Settings -> Plugins?

Comment: @mats-mikkel-rummelhoff Yeah, I did that.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your plugin code. Maybe post a new question with the relevant code in it?